# How to count the number of characters per line from a .txt file and write to another .txt file on separate lines in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and have been struggling with finding a solution to the following problem.  I am trying to count the number of characters in each line of a .txt file and then write these numbers to a different file which will display in separate lines.  For instance:

```
    inputfile:
    This code
    has eight words 
    in it. 


    outputfile:
    9
    15
    6
```

The code I have come up with so far is adding each line count to the previous one.

```
    wrong output:
    9
    24
    30
```

Here is my script:

```
import sys

infilename = sys.argv[1]
outfilename = sys.argv[2]

infile = open (infilename)
outfile = open (outfilename, "w")

charct = 0

for line in (infile):
    line = line.strip("\n")
    charct = charct + len(line)
    outfile.write(str(charct) + "\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

Comment: `outfile.write(str(len(line)) + "\n")`, no need to accumulate.

Comment: `charct = charct + len(line)` why would you add to your counter?

Comment: Thanks. That worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Your current solution adds the current line length to a total for each line with `charct = charct + len(line)`. Replacing that with `charct = len(line)` should do the trick. Aside from that, your code looks fine, though if you're looking to improve it you could look into opening files using the `with` statement.

Comment: I thought my `charct = charct + len(line)` code was just adding each line individually.  I didn't realize that was where I was accumulating my totals.  Thank you for the response, this helped clear up the confusion.